# Import func from subfolder

Tags: go

I'm trying to import a func from a subfolder.

I have a main package

```
package main

import (
    ...
)

func handleRequests() {
    http.HandleFunc("/health", health)
    ...
}

func main() {
    handleRequests()
}
```

And then I have a folder called `health` in which I have a file called `health.go`.

```
package health

import (
    ...
)

func health(writer http.ResponseWriter, _ *http.Request) {
    ...
}
```

What shall my `import` look like and how do I call my health func?

Comment: If you are using modules your import path should be something like `modname/health`, although it is common to put subpackages in a sub folder called `pkg` or `internal` if you do this, your path changes to `modname/pkg/health` . Note that your function health should start with an uppercase letter to be exported

Comment: @PabloFlores *"although it is common to put subpackages in a sub folder called `pkg` or `internal` if you do this"* -- Note that while these may be common they are not an official recommendation. The `internal` package/subfolder serves a special purpose and should not be used for anything but that purpose. The `pkg` package/subfolder, while used in the wild, is recommended *against*, AFAIK.

Comment: @user672009 You'd probably benefit from reading [How to Write Go Code](https://golang.google.cn/doc/code).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At this point, your import statement doesn't mean anything, because it `health` package has no exported function or variable. You should check out the scoping in Go from the language spec. [From here](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Declarations_and_scope)

Maybe consider checking out `go modules`, since it is now the suggested way to handle any go program that has more than a file.

The quick answer is,

your health.go

```
package health

import (
    ...
)

func Handler(writer http.ResponseWriter, _ *http.Request) {
    ...
}
```

your main.go

```
package main

import (
    github.com/blablabla/yourproject/health
)

func handleRequests() {
    http.HandleFunc("/health", health.Handler)
    ...
}

func main() {
    handleRequests()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You must name function starting from uppercase symbol ("Health" instead of "health").

For example: health (your case) is private declaration, and Health would be public.

The same principle with types and variables naming.